# Detect dotted (broken) lines only in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction

I am trying to learn techniques on image feature detection.

I have managed to detect horizontal line(unbroken/continuous), however I am having trouble detecting all the dotted/broken lines in an image.

Here is my test image, as you can see there are dotted lines and some text/boxes etc.

[image: My test Image]

So far I have used the following code which detected only one dotted line.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img=functions.image_resize(img,1000,1000) #function from a script to resize image to fit my screen
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgEdges=cv2.Canny(imgGray,100,250)
imgLines= cv2.HoughLinesP(imgEdges,2,np.pi/100,60, minLineLength = 10, maxLineGap = 100)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in imgLines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('Final Image with dotted Lines detected',img)
```

My output image is below. As you can see I only managed to detect the last dotted line. I have played around with the parameters rho,theta,min/max line but no luck.

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

[image: My Output Image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('test.jpg')

kernel1 = np.ones((3,5),np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((9,9),np.uint8)

imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBW=cv2.threshold(imgGray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

img1=cv2.erode(imgBW, kernel1, iterations=1)
img2=cv2.dilate(img1, kernel2, iterations=3)
img3 = cv2.bitwise_and(imgBW,img2)
img3= cv2.bitwise_not(img3)
img4 = cv2.bitwise_and(imgBW,imgBW,mask=img3)
imgLines= cv2.HoughLinesP(img4,15,np.pi/180,10, minLineLength = 440, maxLineGap = 15)

for i in range(len(imgLines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in imgLines[i]:
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('Final Image with dotted Lines detected', img)
```

Comment: WOW, I am amazed! Your code is so much nicer, I managed to find another approach but it involved a total of 13 different image operation. I noticed, in your approach it doesn't detect the complete dotted line, sometimes it stops half way. How can I over come that?

Comment: Another Question :  Why is it when I do len(imgLines) it doesn't always give me the amount of lines there are eg 4.It always gives me more than 4. That would mean it found more lines for the same line that have different end points and that its not exactly horizontal.

Comment: For a better result, you need to change the parameters in HoughLinesP and observe the result.  I just showed the basic idea of ​​processing.

Comment: Yes, I have played around with that. Can you tell me where you got your knowledge/information about Opencv from? I am very interested in learning all about OpenCV and what it can do. Once again, thanks alot Alex Alex, I am really amazed!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an idea about the dot size, you can use black-hat transform to filter out the dotted lines. Black-hat is the difference between the closing of the image and the image. Then you can try hough line transform.

So, try

Convert bgr-to-gray

Apply black-hat using morphologyEx: this will leave only the black dots in the resulting image.

Invert the result and try hough line transform.

Here, you will have to experiment with the kernel size to filter only the dots. If that proves to be not very robust, another approach would be to use a blob detector. Invert the image and apply opencv blob detector or find contours. Filter the blobs/contours by area. Letters and other structures will have a larger area than the dots, so you can remove any structures that are larger than the dots. Then apply the hough line transform.

Comment: ```#kernel ? 
ImgBlackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(imgGray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT,(7,7)) #apply blackhat
cv2.imshow('ImgBlackhat',ImgBlackhat)

imgInvert=255-ImgBlackhat #invert image
cv2.imshow('ImgInvert',imgInvert)
```

I have tried the above code, but the resulting image after black-hat operation did not leave the black dots only.

Answer (score 0):

because you choose just one line to draw.
You change function draw line to

```
for i, line in enumerate(imgLines):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        cv2.line(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 2)
        print(i, x1, y1, x2, y2)
```