# How to identify dashed lines in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

- I am trying to identify small dashed lines in an image. An example would be identifying copy area in an excel type of application.

[image: This is the test image]

- I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239652/detect-dotted-broken-lines-only-in-an-image-using-opencv#:%7E:text=Invert%20the%20image%20and%20apply,apply%20the%20hough%20line%20transform.).
- I am finding it difficult to chose the filter sizes. So, I tried a different approach using Fourier Transform to check repeatability.
- Given I know the dashed line pixel repetition range I go row by row by using a moving window to check for periodicity by finding dominant frequency in that window.
- If dominant frequency is in range of dashed lines period I set the mask in the mask image. I repeat the same for columns. However this is still failing. Any suggestions/other techniques ?

Here is the code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
    
imgGray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('imgGray', imgGray)

rows,cols = imgGray.shape
    
maskImage = np.full((rows, cols), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
    
kernelL = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, -8, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
    
imgLaplacian = cv2.filter2D(imgGray, cv2.CV_32F, kernelL)
imgResult = imgLaplacian
    
imgResult = np.clip(imgResult, 0, 255)
imgResult = imgResult.astype('uint8')
imgLaplacian = imgResult
    
cv2.imshow('imgLaplacian', imgLaplacian)
    
dashLineSearchInterval = 30
fmaxPixel =9 # minimum interval for dash repetation
fminPixel =7 # maximum interval for dash repetation
stride =2 
    
for y in range(0,rows-dashLineSearchInterval,stride):
    for x in range(0,cols-dashLineSearchInterval,stride):
        kX = (imgLaplacian[y,x:x+ dashLineSearchInterval]).copy()
        kX = kX - np.mean(kX)
        N= dashLineSearchInterval
        freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N)
        ft = np.fft.fft(kX) # fourier transform
        power = ft.real**2 + ft.imag**2 # power 
        maxPowerFreq= np.argmax(power) # dominant frequency
        domFreq = freq [maxPowerFreq]
        if(domFreq<0):
            domFreq = -domFreq
        #print(domFreq)
        if float(1/fmaxPixel) <= domFreq <= float(1/fminPixel) :
            maskImage[y,x:x+dashLineSearchInterval]=255

for x in range(0,cols-dashLineSearchInterval,stride):
    for y in range(0,rows-dashLineSearchInterval,stride):
        kY = (imgLaplacian[y:y+dashLineSearchInterval,x]).copy()
        kY = kY - np.mean(kY)
        N= dashLineSearchInterval
        freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N)
        ft = np.fft.fft(kY) # fourier transform
        power = ft.real**2 + ft.imag**2 # power 
        maxPowerFreq= np.argmax(power) # dominant frequency
        domFreq = freq [maxPowerFreq]
        if(domFreq<0):
            domFreq = -domFreq
        #print(domFreq)
        if float(1/fmaxPixel) <= domFreq <= float(1/fminPixel) :
            maskImage[y:y+dashLineSearchInterval,x]=255
 
cv2.imshow('maskImage', maskImage)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: you might take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482958/), and instead of removing the repetitive lines you can keep them and remove everything else(reverse the operation)

Comment: Are you suggesting I use band pass filter both vertically and horizontally. I have tried this bandpass = scipy.signal.firwin(65, [1/fmaxPixel , 1/fminPixel ], pass_zero=False,fs=1)
convolve1d(convolve1d(image, bp, axis=0), bp, axis=1). This is not working.

Comment: it might work horizontally as the frequency is the same, but not vertically.

Comment: I think the trick is to find changes (lap. filter)  in the images post filtering and threshold it afterwards. Combine results for horizontal and vertical stripes to get the final result. This is the detection [link](https://imgur.com/a/9JOlq8u).Thanks for the kind help @Bilal